# Change auto-lock timeout by GPS?

Tags: gps, lock-screens

I have a PIN to lock the phone so in case someone else gets my phone, they will be deterred from accessing any personal info that might be on it.

But I don't really need this everywhere. When I am at my desk, I always keep the phone there, and I would like for it to not to lock, or to lock less often. (At times, I will be adjusting music, or using the stopwatch or whatever)

Is there a way to change the PIN lock timeout depending on GPS location? If I am not at home or the office, it might as well be on instant lock as soon as the screen goes off.

Comment: If you have Wifi at home and at work you can use this app Unlock with Wifi. https://market.android.com/details?id=com.benhirashima.unlockwithwififree&hl=en

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are apps that disables the lock scren when you are connected to certain WiFi or when your phone cell is connected to certain tower or as per your requirement, on GPS.

I believe, but not sure, [tasker](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) can do it with GPS.

But why not use the WiFi address to disable unlock. I reckon it will be more useful than GPS.

Look at http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/automatically-disable-android-lockscreen-when-connected-to-home-wifi/ for automatically disabling locks creen on WiFi.

Also don't forget to check [llama](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.kebab.Llama), awesome and free location based profile management. You can do tons of stuff based on what cell tower you are connected to.

Comment: +1 I use the Unlock With WiFi app mentioned in that article, find it on the Market at https://market.android.com/details?id=com.benhirashima.unlockwithwifi